# How to swap column values in a data.table using R

Tags: r, data.table

I have the toy data given below.

```
library(data.table)
(tmp <- data.table(R1 = c('D','D','D','T','C'), y = 10:1, R2 = c('D','A','Z','D','D')))

    R1  y R2
 1:  D 10  D
 2:  D  9  A
 3:  D  8  Z
 4:  T  7  D
 5:  C  6  D
 6:  D  5  D
 7:  D  4  A
 8:  D  3  Z
 9:  T  2  D
10:  C  1  D
```

I want to swap values in column `R1` and `R2` so that all the `A` are listed under R1 and the un-common value goes to R2. Can someone show me how it can be done?
Here is the desired output.

```
    R1  y R2
 1:  D 10  D
 2:  D  9  A
 3:  D  8  Z
 4:  D  7  T
 5:  D  6  C
 6:  D  5  D
 7:  D  4  A
 8:  D  3  Z
 9:  D  2  T
10:  D  1  C
```

Here are the performance results of answers provided below -

```
Unit: milliseconds
    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
   akrun 5.524562 5.587740 7.526681 5.605406 5.938955 14.976740     5   b
 r2evans 1.466862 1.489944 1.509321 1.500263 1.536402  1.553134     5  a
```

Comment: If you just need `D`, why cant it be `tmp[, R1 := "D"]`

Comment: I do not want to lose values in ```R1``` and want to transfer them to ```R2``` while replacing ```R1``` with ```D```.

Comment: Apologies for creating confusion. I had chosen the interesting column as ```A``` in my previous column and ```pmin``` and ```pmax``` worked fine. But when I gave an alphabet between ```A to Z```, the solution failed.

Comment: Based on your new data.  I think `tmp[R2 == "D", c("R1", "R2") := .(R2, R1)]`

Comment: Yes, this solution works and looks more intuitive. Can you please answer? I am not sure if swap is happening earlier or ```R2``` is replaced with ```D``` first?

Comment: I updated the answer.  By using the `i` and then assigning the R2, R1 to R1, R2, it does the swapping only for those rows that have a problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the update, we may specify a logical expression on `i` and swap the column values to assign

```
library(data.table)
val <- "D"
tmp[R2 == val, c("R1", "R2") := .(R2, R1)]
```

-output

```
> tmp
    R1  y R2
 1:  D 10  D
 2:  D  9  A
 3:  D  8  Z
 4:  D  7  T
 5:  D  6  C
 6:  D  5  D
 7:  D  4  A
 8:  D  3  Z
 9:  D  2  T
10:  D  1  C
```

Comment: Yeah, this is a good one: it's canonical, likely faster, and clearer too. (It could easily use my `interesting`-set premise as well, replacing both `fifelse`s and such. Nice.)

Comment: This solution works like a charm now and is much intutive. Thanks @akrun. Can you please explain why the swap in columns is happening first and then ```R2``` is replaced with ```val```?

Comment: Can you please explain why the swap in columns is happening first and then ```R2``` is replaced with ```val```? I am wondering how the sequence of events are executing.

Comment: `R2` is not being replaced with `val`; `R2 == val` is the conditional, so only rows that match that condition will swap the values.

Comment: @Saurabh When you do the `tmp[R2 == val]`, it subset the data for only those rows where R2 values are 'D', in the `j`, we are just swapping the column values to the R1, R2 or viceversa

Comment: Got it. It is indeed a very clever and intutive solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that the other answer may be the most applicable, but in case your needs are not based on lexicographic sorting (and indeed just on presence in a set of "interesting" values), then

```r
interesting <- c("A")
tmp[, c("R1", "R2") := .(
  fifelse(R2 %in% interesting & !R1 %in% interesting, R2, R1),
  fifelse(R2 %in% interesting & !R1 %in% interesting, R1, R2))]
tmp
#         x     R1     R2
#     <int> <char> <char>
#  1:     1      A      A
#  2:     2      A      F
#  3:     3      A      T
#  4:     4      A      G
#  5:     5      A      I
#  6:     6      A      A
#  7:     7      A      F
#  8:     8      A      T
#  9:     9      A      G
# 10:    10      A      I
```

I confess that this looks a little clumsy, double-calculating the conditional. That could easily be worked in more efficiently as a temporary variable either inside or outside of the `tmp` frame, such as:

```r
tmp[, swap := R2 %in% interesting & !R1 %in% interesting
  ][, c("R1", "R2") := .(fifelse(swap, R2, R1), fifelse(swap, R1, R2))
  ][, swap := NULL]
```

If you are certain that `R2 %in% interesting` is perfectly aligned with `!R2 %in% interesting` (that is, it is never the case that both `R1` and `R2` are *interesting*, ... or you don't care about swapping if both are interesting, as in rows 1 and 6), then you can simplify that down to

```r
tmp[, c("R1", "R2") := .(
  fifelse(R2 %in% interesting, R2, R1),
  fifelse(R2 %in% interesting, R1, R2))]
```

Comment: Thanks, @r2evans. I have changed the question a bit and placed ```D``` as ```interesting``` value instead of ```A```. Your solution worked in that situation too.

Comment: I'm glad it works for you. The addition of `y` doesn't seem to really have any effect, is there something missing in my answer?

Comment: Your solution is much faster. I have shared the performance above.

Comment: That's surprising, to be honest.